# Angular router: how to pass data from lazy loading module to canactivate service?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
/* Import Routes Config */
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ShopComponent } from './home/shop.component';
import { DataResolver } from './data-resolver';

const routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        canActivate: ['canActivateservice']
        children: [
            { path: 'contact', loadChildren: './src/contact/contact.module#ContactModule' },
        ]
    },
    { path: 'about', loadChildren: './src/about/about.module#AboutModule' },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];


export default RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

like in above code we are calling contact module and  i am using  canActivate guard

```
import { Route, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact.component';
import { MapComponent } from './map.component';
import { DefaultComponent } from './default.component';

export const ContactRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: '',
        data: { id: '1', desc: 'foo' },
        component: ContactComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: DefaultComponent },
        ]
    }
];

export default RouterModule.forChild(ContactRoutes);
```

and in above code we are passing data from here

```
 canActivate(next: ActivatedRoute,state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        console.log(next)
        });
    }
```

in above  code if if do console.log(next),i don't see any data in next

Answer (score 0):

Data is available in the data property of the ActivatedRoute object

```
 canActivate(next: ActivatedRoute,state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        console.log(next.data)
        });
    }
```

Comment: Which says there is no data passed in the ActivatedRoute. Add data: {  } in the Routes array

Comment: Add canActivate: ['canActivateservice'] for the ContactRoutes

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `data` in same level as `canActivate`.

```
export const ContactRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ContactComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', 
              data: { id: '1', desc: 'foo' },
              canActivate: [canActivateService],
              component: DefaultComponent 
            },
        ]
    }
];
```

Then get data in `ActivatedRoute`, like Ininiv said.

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRoute,state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        console.log(next.data)
        });
    }
```